# Как отметить радио в добавленном элементе?

Tags: jquery

в документ добавился html с radiobutton таким образом:

```
$('.wrap').html('<input id="name" type="radio" name="name" value="1"> .. итд.');
```

$('.wrap #name').prop('checked',true); не работает.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.wrap').html('<input id="name" type="radio" name="name" value="1">');
$('.wrap #name').prop('checked',true);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap"></div>
```